# Failed Review Audit of copied answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I failed a [first post review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7330071) today, where the answer given was by a 16 rep user. The answer itself seemed to be very good, but as he had only 16 rep, and it showed up in the first post queue, I was not sure if he didn't just copy & paste the answer from an existing answer. So I opened the question, saw that someone with much more rep answered the same (it is also the accepted answer) and went back to my review. I downvoted then, and wanted to flag it as "stolen" - but I failed the review. Now I don't know if the answer in the review was really the one by JuniorCompressor and he only had 16 rep at that time (which doesn't seem to be possible, given his many answers before that time) or the answer by the 16 rep user got deleted (which I can't see, I'm not even close to 10k rep).

Now I only see three possibility's:

1. The reviewsystem presented me the copy & pasted answer from a new user which was already deleted, and then presented me the accepted answer as right
2. The reviewsystem presented me JuniorCompressor with 16 rep, and I just didn't check the names (Honestly I don't know if there were the same names, but I doubt it.)
3. I'm completely missing something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The audit system is known to fake user names and rep totals in known-good audits. It won't use a post that's been deleted for a known-good audit base. Therefore, #2 is the closest; it presented you with the accepted answer, faked the user name, rep, post score, and the accepted field, and your check misled you into flagging it.

(It won't fake profile pictures, for some reason. If you see a low-rep user with a capture of a Winterbash hat, chances are extremely high it's an audit. And, in any case, if you see the same picture on the review post as on the accepted answer, or if the answer link scrolls on the question to a post that is not deleted, that's a clear sign that it's known-good.)

I do have to commend you for checking for plagiarism; this is rather difficult to manage properly and quite under-performed.

Comment: Oh well - didn't knew it fakes usernames and reps. Thanks a lot for your help!